# How to configure Mediatek MT7601 USB WiFi adapter on UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb

I seek help in the installation of MediaTek MT7601 USB WiFi Adapter.  The output of commands

```
i.  dmesg | tail
ii. lsmod  and
iii. iwconfig are given below
```

The output of `dmesg | tail` is as follows

```
[  224.675499] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  224.705638] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
[  224.705653] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  224.705663] usb 3-1: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  224.705671] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[  224.705678] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 1.0
[  224.726882] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ra0: link is not ready
[  360.496816] type=1400 audit(1426480974.025:65): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=2752 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  360.496831] type=1400 audit(1426480974.025:66): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2752 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  360.497874] type=1400 audit(1426480974.029:67): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2752 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Output of `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
mt7601Usta            557531  0 
ath3k                  13110  0 
btusb                  27580  0 
bnep                   18895  2 
rfcomm                 53664  8 
bluetooth             342208  23 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45440  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    59259  1 
intel_rapl             18301  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    13845  0 
intel_powerclamp       14239  0 
coretemp               13195  0 
kvm_intel             132651  0 
kvm                   388310  1 kvm_intel
crc32_pclmul           12967  0 
aesni_intel            18156  0 
snd_hda_intel          42794  3 
snd_hda_codec         164067  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
aes_i586               16995  1 aesni_intel
xts                    12749  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
lrw                    13057  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm                85501  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
gf128mul               14503  2 lrw,xts
arc4                   12536  2 
ablk_helper            13357  1 aesni_intel
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
cryptd                 15578  1 ablk_helper
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
ath9k                 144602  0 
snd_rawmidi            25135  1 snd_seq_midi
tpm_infineon           17164  0 
ath9k_common           13359  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              438205  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
snd_seq                55383  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
ath                    23922  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              546067  1 ath9k
mei_me                 18195  0 
joydev                 17101  0 
serio_raw              13230  0 
lpc_ich                16864  0 
parport_pc             31981  0 
cfg80211              409394  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
mei                    66737  1 mei_me
i915                  710013  3 
ppdev                  17391  0 
snd_timer              28584  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
shpchp                 32128  0 
snd                    60939  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12600  1 snd
toshiba_acpi           18301  0 
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40836  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
drm_kms_helper         48868  1 i915
toshiba_bluetooth      12748  0 
sparse_keymap          13708  1 toshiba_acpi
wmi                    18673  1 toshiba_acpi
drm                   244037  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
video                  18903  1 i915
mac_hid                13037  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
usb_storage            48417  3 
hid_generic            12492  0 
usbhid                 47070  0 
hid                    87604  2 hid_generic,usbhid
e1000e                223034  0 
psmouse                91357  0 
ahci                   25579  1 
sdhci_pci              18535  0 
ptp                    18445  1 e1000e
libahci                27214  1 ahci
sdhci                  37779  1 sdhci_pci
pps_core               18799  1 ptp
```

Output of `iwconfig`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

ra0       Ralink STA  

In above output, I want to configure "ra0, Ralink STA".  the command 
modinfo mt7601Usta
gives no error.  The driver has been installed in "/etc/Wireless/..."
```

Thanks in advance for any help, advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `wpa_supplicant` command.

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Note: *Don't* provide `-D wext/nl80211/cfg80211`, as driver automatically takes it.

Edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` to provide your WiFi ESSID and pass-key:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="YOUR-WIFI-ESSID"
    psk="your-wifi-password"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Now I can see the file wpa_supplicant.conf file at /etc/dbus-1/system.d/wpa_supplicant.conf